# Selecting on SQL with three conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a list of recipes, the amount of money it will cost to produce those recipes and the name of the chefs that have prepared those recipes.

I want to create a list of all the chef names, the name of the recipes, the number of recipes each have prepared, and the average price of the recipes they have prepared.

So far I have

```
SELECT (DISTINCT chefName) FROM Chef
AND
SELECT COUNT(nameRecipe) FROM Recipe
AND
SELECT AVG(PriceOfRecipe) FROM Recipe;
```

but I get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

What could this be?

Comment: Did you check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server for the right syntax?  And if not, why not (given that's what the message ***told you to do***)?

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: It seems you need to read up on how to build up SQL queries. In your case - I don't see even logic between those three queries, even if you'll use `UNION` between `select`s, instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
SELECT chefName, AVG(PriceofRecipe), COUNT(nameRecipe) FROM Recipe GROUP BY chefName
```